# How can I use a wildcard character inside an sqlite3 command, which is inside an adb shell?

Tags: android, shell, sqlite, escaping, adb

Here is what does work for a specific case:

```
adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.company.product.contents/databases/contents.db "update items set kind=1234 where key = 'contents:com.company.service.exampleapp'"
```

But due to various package name conventions I am never sure what the exact packagename/key will be, so I want to use a wildcard. This isn't working for me:

```
adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.company.product.contents/databases/contents.db "update items set kind=1234 where key like '%exampleapp%'"
```

I get the command echo'd back as :  "...  where key like ''  ..."

No matter what I do, including using escape characters and various combinations of single/double quotes, it also ignores whatever's after the wildcard/percent sign.

Comment: Your host PC environment (OS/shell/programming language if any) also matters for proper escaping.

Comment: Yes sorry, I'm just using this in a Windows command line.